# Mapping an "import" name to a PyPI name?

Tags: python

This is for work on `pydeps --externals` (https://github.com/thebjorn/pydeps) which lists the external packages imported by a module, e.g.:

```
c:\github\pydeps> pydeps --externals pydeps
[
    "configparser",
    "enum",
    "stdlib_list",
    "yaml"
]
```

meaning that these four modules are the only imports of dependent packages that needs to be installed(*). This can e.g. be fed into something that creates (or checks) a `requirements.txt` file.

I realize there are problems with all four lines, but this question relates to the last two (`stdlib_list` and `yaml`) which come from packages(*) named `stdlib-list` and `PyYAML` respectively.

IIUC there is no way to find the package name from the module name, even if the dependencies have been installed. Is this still correct?

I've found `site-packages/*.dist-info/top_level.txt`, but it doesn't seem I can trust that this file it's always present (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0427/#the-dist-info-directory). This leaves searching `site-packages/*.dist-info/RECORD` for `<importname>/__init__.pyc?`  Is there an existing API for accessing this info?  `pkginfo` looked promising, but wasn't:

```
import pkginfo, stdlib_list
print pkginfo.Installed(yaml).package_name    # print "yaml"
```

The other option is to keep a large mapping of module/import name -> package/pip-install name.  I see others have had this idea, e.g. https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs/blob/master/pipreqs/mapping, but is there a more official way (or a pypi package?)

(*) I haven't found any unique and consistently used name for the "thing" that is `pip install`-ed. I try to call that "thing" a *package*, and "things" that are imported for *modules* -- I'm sure that is controversial ;-)

Comment: PyPI stands for "Python Package Index", which makes it reasonable to call the "thing" a package.

Comment: The file `top_level.txt` is not wheel specific. It even gets created in a virtualenv if you install PyYAML and if first deinstalled the wheel package. Under what circumstances do you think it is not created? Not sure though since when installing with pip does this (and/or if it is dependent on the version of setuptools as well).

Comment: @Anthon I assumed I couldn't rely on it being present because `top_level.txt` isn't listed in the contents of the `.dist-info` directory in the PEP. Quickly checking the 216 packages in my site-packages there are 2 packages without `top_level.txt` (`pycrypto-2.6.1.dist-info` and `pyyaml-3.12.dist-info`).

Comment: @thebjorn I have the `top_level.txt` in PyYAML 3.13 (Python 3.6), so  I created a new temporary virtualenv (python 2.7) and installed 3.12  to see where the differences comes from. That one has the `top_level.txt` as well, as does pycrypto2.6.1 when installed. Are you sure all your packages were installed using `pip`? Nothing happened like using your systems package manager PyYAML? Or remember installed PyYAML before upgrading `pip`/`distutils`? Just thinking out loud here, wondering about the difference between set-ups

Comment: @Anthon windows, so no os-level package manager. I'm in a long-lived virtualenv though, so many packages have been installed with older versions of pip / setuptools (I'm unsure what the relationship is between stdlib distutils and setuptools on py2.7).  pip uninstall + install with current pip/setuptools created top_level.txt for both packages...

Comment: @thebjorn `setuptools` has used `top_level.txt` since 2005 and `pip` at least a for 4 years when available. But `distutils` seems only to have started using it on 2017/12/08 and the private copy of that in `pip` was added 2018/01/08. So unless you can guarantee/force that people have installed with a pip version after that, you probably cannot assume that top_level.txt is there.